# cubeIDE (eclips) project importer not working

Tags: eclipse, stm32, stm32cubeide

when i try to import projects via "file/open projects from file system" it shows project but when i press finish nothing happens no error or nothing and project doesn't show up in project explorer.
tho if i do it through "file/import/existing projects into workspace" it's ok.
even when i double click on .cproject and .project files nothing happens even cubeIDE doesn't open.

i searched and tried separating workspace and project folder as advised but no changes.
can you help me please it wasn't like this the only thing i did was to create a new wokspace but now even the old workspaces are like that.

Comment: Importing existing project into workspace is the correct thing to do, if it is not already in that workspace.

Comment: I don't get your point can you explain, btw what that has to do with double click not working anymore

Comment: apparently it could be caused by recent updates, what is your version if you don't have problems like this? @pmacfarlane ( i forgot to mention in last comment)

Answer (score 0):

Same thing here.

Since the last minor update a week ago, we are unable to work on existing projects.

The open (active) project is no longer open. We tried to re-open the project but after pressing "Finish" we neither see the project tree nor the files within (as stated by the OP).

Attempts to import the old project leads to a similar result. Here a new subdirectory is created within the old workspace with only some cube-related files and everything else from our (complex) project setup is lost.

I suspect an internal change that the new CubeIDE somehow tries to add an additional directory layer below/above the projects workspace directory.